# Removing swf object with javascript

Tags: javascript, object, swfobject

I am having a big problem over here. I am building a webpage having little flash animations in it. But the thing is I am not that familiar with flash and all related topics... It's a recipe for long nights.

What I am trying to do: 

 Here you see the code for embedding my swf object in html. (it is statically; without js)

```
<object id="removeme" data="objects/junge_leute.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="173" height="190">
<param name="movie" value="flash/junge_leute.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale">
<param name="menu" value="false">
<param name="loop" value="false" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

And in actionscript I call (after animation is done) a javascript method.

Until now everything is woking fine! Here comes the problem: With javascript I need to remove that object from code. How can I achieve that. I tried .empty(), .remove().. even
It is very urgent. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('removeme').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('removeme'));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SWFObject 2.2, you can use the [`swfobject.removeSWF`](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.removeSWF%28objElemIdStr%29) method.

```
swfobject.removeSWF("removeme");
```